# Sencha Touch: animation on dispatch

Tags: sencha-touch

How to use animations on Ext.dispatch ?

This code doesn't work for me (layout type is 'card'):

```
Ext.dispatch({
 controller: 'main',
 action: 'whoweare',
 animation: { type: 'slide', direction: 'right' }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the animation object you pass to the controller while calling setActiveItem of your viewport in the controller.

So, in the whoweare function of your main controller:

```
whoweare: function(options) {
    newPanel = new myApp.views.myPanel(); 
    myApp.views.viewport.setActiveItem(newPanel, options.animation);
}
```